# how to implement put http request using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

below i have i code for http request get using this api https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts , what i want to know how to use put using alamofire to update the data on the api , i want to update it using the id

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
```

my alamofire get request code

```
func demoApi() {
        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
//            case .success(_):
//                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
//                print("Response \(json)")
//                for item in json {
//
//                    if let name = item["name"] as? String {
//                        self.titleArray.append(name)
//                        print("ang name:" , name)
//
//                    }
//
//                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
//                    }
//                }
//                break

            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")
                for item in json {

                    self.getAllDetail.append(item)

                    // if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                    //   self.titleArray.append(title)
                    // }

                }
                if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like , for info you get the sample from [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

```
  let  params  = ["userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"] as [String: Any]


Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {


            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")


                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: dont worry i can inplement it dynamically

Comment: @DurnKurvirck -- for e.g `let  params  = ["userId": pass your ID,`

Answer (score 0):

**For Future references:**

```
  let parameters = ["userId": 1,
                  "id": 1,
                  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
                  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"] as [String : Any]



let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
response in
switch response.result {
case .success:
print(response)

break
case .failure(let error):

print(error)
}
}
```

Comment: My pleasure @DurnKurvirck This was just for future references with a POST Method.

Comment: Hi , i want to ask a question , @abh

Comment: i cant seem to print these data "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },  , how do i convert that to [] ?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question?

Comment: i wanted to print it these way  print("You selected  #\( getTempDetails["occurrence:",["name"] as? String  ?? "" )!") , is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168541/discussion-between-durn-kurvirck-and-abhirajsinh-thakore).

Comment: the format from the api is "occurrence": {
            "name": "once"
        },